# getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions when opening app on emulator

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am updating my question because previous one was not upto the standards of stackoverflow.

I am getting following exception related firebase when trying to open the app in emulator.

```
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions
                                                                at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zzbu(Unknown Source)
                                                                at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source)
                                                                at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1058)
                                                                at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source)
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4819)
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4432)
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4372)
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:141)
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1294)
                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
                                                                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

App is running fine on my actual device. Above error is only raising on emulator.
I haven't use firebase in my whole application but I am using Google Play Services to get current location.
Following is my gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
        packagingOptions {
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE' // will not include NOTICE file
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE' // will not include LICENSE file

        }
        compileSdkVersion 23
        buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.wingsapp"
            minSdkVersion 16
            targetSdkVersion 23
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            multiDexEnabled true
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
        compile files('libs/httpclient-4.0-alpha4.jar')
        compile files('libs/android-query-full.0.26.7.jar')
        compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpclient-android', version: '4.3.5.1'
        compile('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3') {
            exclude module: "httpclient"
        }


        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.3.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.0'
        compile 'com.joooonho:selectableroundedimageview:1.0.1'
        compile 'com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.0.0'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.0.0'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.0.0'
    }
```

P.S. : I have developed this app on android studio 1.5 and it was running on emulator also, now I have upgraded to android studio 2.1.1 and since then getting above exception on only emulator.

Comment: provide more information, we are not mind readers you know

Comment: we need more info...please

Comment: please post your your `Activty` or logcat

Comment: what type of error you are getting, probably null pointer exception / array index out of bound exception.? post your  logcat details.

Comment: can you post full logcat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proper Solution I found for above question is to use latest version of Android Studio for installing in ubuntu. I upgrade to Android Studio version 2.1.1 from 1.5 and problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Thats because you are using Wrapper type Integer array to hold images . You shoud use int[] instead of Integer[]

Comment: Change the Adapter class to extends BaseAdapter . Because ArrayAdapter Class is for single TextView Item .BaseAdapter is the best solution for Customising list view . If You are using ArrayAdapter then you should skip  super(contex, R.layout.mylist, name); So just Use Base Adapter .

Answer (score 0):

The method `imageView.setImageResource(int id)` expects an integer that is present as a resource in your Android project. The res/ folder of your project would contain drawables, layouts and UI components like buttons, textviews etc. which can be referenced by their respective id's. 
Usually images are placed in their respective drawable/ folder depending on the size and resolution of images. You can resolve your problem by importing the images into the drawable/ folder of your project, and referring to them by a auto-generated id. For example, say you have an image of name "icon.png" in your drawable folder, that you want to set as the image resource for an imageview. What you do is, you refer to this image using `R`, in this way: `R.drawable.icon`. `R.drawable.icon` would result in a integer that is auto generated for the "icon.png" file in your res/ folder and you can use `imageView.setImageResource(R.id.icon)` to set this image as the imageview's image resource. This is the standard way of referring to images and other resources with their `int` id, instead of passing a random integer to methods such as `imageView.setImageResource(int id)`.

Comment: but I am using listview so can not use R.drawable... because it will print one image on all list items

Comment: If you want to display a separate image for every entry in your listview, you can create a mapping between the list entry and the image you want to display. Import all the possible images a listview entry can have in your drawable/ folder, and find out dynamically which of these images are required for a particular entry. I suspect you will know which image is required for a list item, depending on other parameters of the item like item name. You can even add an id field to your list items and dynamically update your imageview with a particular image, based on the id of the item.